# Does running fsck manually (without a -a or -p option) formats the partition?

Tags: partitioning

I had a problem where i could not log in to my system. I was logged into recovery mode everytime. Then I found this guy here ( https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336395 ) had the same problem and I also found out that my issues are same. Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found on a partition. I have to run fcsk manually on it. Will it format my data? Or do i need to keep a backup first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to run fcsk manually on it. Will it format my data?

- You can't format a mounted partition.
- `fsck` (filesystem check) is to repair a filesystem; not for formatting.
- the commands `mkfs` (make filesytem), `dd` or `fdisk` can be used to format a disk.

So no, fsck does not format a disk.

> Or do i need to keep a backup first?

Why the need to ask this. You need to backup anything worth saving regardless of any reason; and that backup needs to be somewhere stored other than in the same room. It is a computer. Computers can break beyond repair.

Comment: re: "*Computers can break beyond repair*." That made me giggle. **Every** computer can be repaired :-) It all depends on how good of a tech you hire :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you dual-boot with Windows, if you've installed a driver to be able to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions, remove that driver asap, as it corrupts Linux partitions.

Proper use of fsck will not format your data.

Backups are always a good thing, even if there's not a problem with your system.

To check your file system for errors...

**For 17.10 or older...**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**For 18.04 or newer...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: thanks for your tip, i will keep that in my mind. However, i have used ubuntu in dual boot for about six months and few days ago i decided to go with ubuntu only. That's where i faced some problems.